# Photodiode, analog electronic

Tags: analog, simulation, optoelectronics

I am a beginner PSPICE, in simulation electrical and electronics circuits. I want to simulate a schematic with the program Micro-CAP 12. I want to look for some graphics from a photodiode PIN  which is  a InGaAs Photodiode IG22-Series, I want to monitor follow parameters:

- responsivity (A/W) vs wavelength(nm);
- dark current (A) vs reverse voltage (V);
- shunt resistance vs. temperature;
- detectivity vs. shunt x area;
- capacitance vs. reverse voltage;
- responsivity temperature coefficient.

And at transistor BFP420 I want to monitor some graphics at the following parameters:

- total power dissipation Ptot = ƒ(TS);
- permissible pulse load RthJS = ƒ(tp);
- permissible pulse loadPtotmax/PtotDC = ƒ(tp);
- collector-base capacitance Ccb= ƒ(VCB)f = 1MHz;
- transition frequency fT= ƒ(IC) f = 2 GHz VCE = parameter in V;
- power gain Gma, Gms, |S21|² = ƒ (f) VCE = 2 V, IC = 20 mA;
- power gain Gma, Gms = ƒ (IC) VCE = 2V f = parameter in GHz;
- collector-base capacitance Ccb = f (VCB) VBE = 0, f = 1MHz;
- noise figure F = f (IC) VCE = 2 V, ZS = ZSopt;
- noise figure F = f (IC) VCE = 2 V, f = 1.8 GHz;

I do not know how to begin. Please help me. I accept, if is necessary  any simulator of circuits.

Comment: 1) you want to use a **circuit simulator**, then you need a **circuit**. 2) do not treat a circuit simulator as "I put something in, something comes out and what comes out is **the truth**". It does not work like that, if you **misunderstand** how a circuit simulator works you could make it behave in unexpected ways. Then what comes out is **nonsense**. How would you know that is so? You have to do some **hand calculations** so that you **know what to expect**. Then use the simulator to **confirm that** and get **more accurate data**.

Comment: 3) a simulator relies on a **model** of a component. If the responsivity vs wavelength isn't modeled then you can (try to) simulate it but you will get a **wrong answer**. 4) making those transistor parameter plots like Ccb and Noise Figure, is a **complex task** even for experienced electrical engineers. Also those values are for **certain conditions** which depend on the circuit which you do not have. All-in-all I think you're way over your head here, you want **too much** for your skill level.

Comment: I have a circuit .I kow that I must have a calculation model,which help at behavior characterization of component.The problem is I do not know how to begin.

Comment: If you already know PSpice (at least a little bit) why are you using MicroCap to do this simulation instead of PSpice?